# TensorFlow | create image dataset, labelled by filename

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.dataset

Im trying to create Tensorflow dataset to train my model. I have a folder full of tagged photos, tagging is part of the files names.

do you have a reasonable way to load the dataset for training without splitting it to different directories?

example:
for files:

- ./dataset/path/img0_cat.bmp
- ./dataset/path/img1_dog.bmp
- ./dataset/path/img2_horse.bmp
- ./dataset/path/img3_cat.bmp
- ./dataset/path/img4_dog.bmp
- ./dataset/path/img5_horse.bmp
- ./dataset/path/img6_dog.bmp
- ./dataset/path/img7_cat.bmp
- ./dataset/path/img8_horse.bmp
- ./dataset/path/img9_cat.bmp
- ./dataset/path/img10_dog.bmp

expected output: tf.Dataset labeled as one hot for (cat, dog, horse)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your responses

The way I solved it is as follows:

```
classNames = ['dog', 'cat', 'horse']

def getLabel(file_path):
    # Convert the path to a list of path components
    fileName = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)[-1]
    # get label name from filename
    className = tf.strings.split(fileName, '_')[1]
    className = tf.strings.split(className, '.')[0]
    # get one_hot vector boolean
    one_hot = className == classNames
    # cast vector type to integer 
    return tf.cast(one_hot, dtype=tf.int8, name=None)

def getImage(file_path):
    # Load the raw data from the file as a string
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    # Convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
    img = tf.io.decode_bmp(img, channels=3)
    # cast tf.Tensor type to uint8 
    return tf.cast(img, dtype=tf.uint8, name=None)

def process_path(file_path):
    label = getLabel(file_path)
    img = getImage(file_path)
    return img, label

path = './dataset/path/*.bmp'
ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path)
ds = ds.map(process_path)
```

At the end of this process you get a Tensorflow trainable dataset (batch size requires more configuration, see reference), labels as one-hot vector.

when running:

```
for image, label in ds.take(5):
     imageShape = image.numpy().shape
     label = label.numpy()
     labelName = class_names[np.argmax(label)]
     print('Image Shape: {}, Label: {}, LabelName: {}'.format(imageShape, label, labelName))
```

you got:

```
Image Shape: (180, 180, 3), Label: [1 0 0], LabelName: dog
Image Shape: (180, 180, 3), Label: [0 1 0], LabelName: cat
Image Shape: (180, 180, 3), Label: [0 0 1], LabelName: horse
Image Shape: (180, 180, 3), Label: [1 0 0], LabelName: dog
Image Shape: (180, 180, 3), Label: [0 1 0], LabelName: cat
```

Reference:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images

Answer (score 0):

You can try assigning an ID to each path and gather paths based on whatever IDs you're using on your training set.

If you're using Tensorflow, the [Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) documentation has informative methods in loading data. Specifically,

`dataset_dog = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("./dataset/path/*dog.bmp)`

Comment: thanks, 
it generate dataset with dog only.
I used this function but to generate all the file and create the labels as part of input pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

here is the whole enchilada. I prefer to use pandas datasets along with the ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe because it is flexible. I created a directory single with 10 images of cranes and 10 images of albaross. Filenames are of the form
0_crane.jpf, 1_crane.jpg etc ... 10_albatross, 11_albatross ..... Code below process this directory. Create a dataframe df, then splits it into a train_df, valid_df and a test_df. Then 3 image data generators are created for train_gen, test_gen and valid_gen. I used a standard model I usually use and trained the model. Then evaluated the test ste with 100% accuracy. Code is below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Dropout,Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, Adamax
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

sdir = r'c:\temp\single'
filepaths=[]
labels=[]
flist=os.listdir(sdir)
for f in flist:
    fpath=os.path.join(sdir,f)   
    filepaths.append(fpath)
    index1=f.rfind('_')+1
    index2=f.rfind('.')    
    klass=f[index1:index2]     
    labels.append(klass)
Fseries=pd.Series(filepaths, name='filepaths')
Lseries=pd.Series(labels, name='labels')
df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)
# now you can use train_test_split to create a train_df, a test_df and a valid_df
trsplit=.8
vsplit=.1
dsplit=vsplit/(1-trsplit)
train_df, dummy_df=train_test_split (df, train_size=trsplit, shuffle=True, random_state=123, stratify=df['labels'])
valid_df, test_df= train_test_split(dummy_df, train_size=dsplit, shuffle=True, random_state=123, stratify =dummy_df['labels'])
print ('train_df length: ', len(train_df), ' test_df length: ', len(test_df) ,'  valid_df length: ', len(valid_df))

# create a train_gen,  a valid_gen and a test_gen
# for trgen you can specify augmentations like horizontal_flip, vertical_flip etc
img_size=(224,224)
batch_size=16
trgen=ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,rotation_range=20, width_shift_range=.2,
                                  height_shift_range=.2, zoom_range=.2   )
tvgen=ImageDataGenerator()
train_gen=trgen.flow_from_dataframe(train_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels',target_size=img_size,
                                   class_mode='categorical', color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
valid_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe(valid_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels',target_size=img_size,
                                   class_mode='categorical', color_mode='rgb', shuffle=False, batch_size=2)
test_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe(test_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels',target_size=img_size,
                                   class_mode='categorical', color_mode='rgb', shuffle=False, batch_size=2)
train_files=train_gen.filenames
classes=list(train_gen.class_indices.keys())
class_count=len(classes)
labels=train_gen.labels
images, labels=next(train_gen)
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12))
for i in range (len(images)):
    plt.subplot(4,4, i+1) 
    index=np.argmax(labels[i])
    class_name=classes[index]
    plt.title(class_name, color='yellow', fontsize=18)   
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(images[i]/255)
plt.show()
# build a model
img_shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], 3)
model_name='EfficientNetB5'
base_model=tf.keras.applications.efficientnet.EfficientNetB5(include_top=False, weights="imagenet",input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max') 
# Note you are always told NOT to make the base model trainable initially- that is WRONG you get better results leaving it trainable
base_model.trainable=True
x=base_model.output
x=BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
x = Dense(1024, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l = 0.016),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006) ,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(rate=.3, seed=123)(x)
x = Dense(128, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l = 0.016),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006) ,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(rate=.45, seed=123)(x)        
output=Dense(class_count, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
lr=.001 # start with this learning rate
model.compile(Adamax(learning_rate=lr), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 

epochs=5
history=model.fit(x=train_gen,  epochs=epochs, verbose=1,  validation_data=valid_gen,
               validation_steps=None,  shuffle=False,  initial_epoch=0)

loss, acc =model.evaluate(test_gen)
print (' accuracy on test set is: ', acc* 100, '%')
```